# Spring/JPA/Hibernate How to Perform Join of Two Entities In One Repository

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

First let's say we have two tables. One table is an **Employee** table with the following columns:

```
EMPLOYEE:
------------------------
emp_id (int, primary key)
emp_name (varchar(125))
emp_dept (foreign key)
emp_intro (text)
```

The other table is a **Department** table with the following columns:

```
DEPARTMENT:
-----------
dept_id (int, primary key)
dept_label (varchar(25))
```

Here is a sample of the table's values

```
DEPARTMENT:
------------------------
dept_id    | dept_label
------------------------
 1         | Sales
------------------------
 2         | Technology
------------------------
 3         | Finance
```

In order to return the employee's info with a status label, we need to either perform a JOIN:

```
SELECT e, d.dept_label FROM employees JOIN department d ON d.dept_id = e.emp_dept
```

or a multi-table select:

```
SELECT e.emp_id, e.emp_name, d.dept_label, e.emp_intro FROM employees e, department d WHERE e.emp_dept = d.dept_id
```

However, when using JPA/Hibernate, we need to create two classes:

**Employee.java**

```
package com.example.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "emp_id")
    private long emp_id;

    @Column(name = "emp_name")
    private String emp_name;

    @Column(name = "emp_dept")
    private Integer emp_dept;

    @Column(name = "emp_intro")
    private String emp_intro;

    public long getEmp_id() {
        return emp_id;
    }

    public void setEmp_id(long emp_id) {
        this.emp_id = emp_id;
    }

    public String getEmp_name() {
        return emp_name;
    }

    public void setEmp_name(String emp_name) {
        this.emp_name = emp_name;
    }

    public Integer getEmp_dept() {
        return emp_dept;
    }

    public void setEmp_dept(Integer emp_dept) {
        this.emp_dept = emp_dept;
    }

    public String getEmp_intro() {
        return emp_intro;
    }

    public void setEmp_intro(String emp_intro) {
        this.emp_intro = emp_intro;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

}
```

**Department.java**

```
package com.example.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "departments")
public class Department implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "dept_id")
    private long dept_id;

    @Column(name = "dept_label")
    private String dept_label;

    public long getDept_id() {
        return dept_id;
    }

    public void setDept_id(long dept_id) {
        this.dept_id = dept_id;
    }

    public String getDept_label() {
        return dept_label;
    }

    public void setDept_label(String dept_label) {
        this.dept_label = dept_label;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

}
```

Then, there is the repository (DAO):

**EmployeeRepository**

```
package com.example.repository;

import.java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import com.example.entities.Employee;

public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

    @Query("select e, d.dept_label FROM Employee e JOIN Department d ON "
    + "d.dept_id = e.emp_id")
    public List<Employee> return getEmployees();

}
```

and lastly, the Java controller that binds the classed query to an endpoint of the application:

**EmployeeController.java**

```
package com.example.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.example.entities.Department;
import com.example.entities.Employee;
import com.example.repository.EmployeeRepository;

@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository er;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getEmployees")
    public @ResponseBody List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return er.getEmployees();
    }

}
```

I have already tested this entire structure with only retrieving rows inside of the Employee table (i.e. @Query("SELECT e FROM Employee e") ) and everything returns as is.

**MY MAIN ISSUE** is how does one return a JOIN QUERY while the query is inside of a specific class (table), being Employee, if I require contents inside of Department?

I've already tried @JoinColumn annotations and that didn't work as well (perhaps I did it wrong).

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: object-oriented languages allow object references forming relations between objects. You have none of those. A relation is not a long that just happens to represent some object of some other class, it should be an object reference! That is at the O-O level, not even at the JPA level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to use raw joins to do that, just use proper relation mapping. Relation between `Employee` and `Departament` sounds like `@ManyToOne` or `@ManyToMany`.
You will be able to eg `employee.getDepartament()` or query by `employee.departament.name=:name`

http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/ManyToMany

You can even map bidirectional relations so you will be able to get deparament from employee, as well as all employees from given deparaments

PS. `@JoinColumn` is used to delare DB columnt used for joins it it is different then created by selected named strategies (usualy entityname_id). Actual relation mapping is done by declaring `@OneToOne` `@OneToMany` `@ManyToMany` and those can but doesn't have to be used with `@JoinColumn`. It is strict `JPA` question.

[Here you have complete documentation of JPA 2.1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf) 
It describes in details how to declare relations as well as `@MappedSuperclass`, inheritance strategies and all other usefull stuff.

Comment: I actually followed the JPA documentation for the JPA 2.1 specification: according to the docs, there is no annotation required in the Department class. I want to use the Department.label property, so I must add @ OneToOne unidirectional. I add three lines: 1) private Department department 2) @ OneToOne annotation, 3) the getter under this line and then 4) the setter under that line. I then receive an 'Invalid column name 'department' error. Any idea? (

Comment: @MindsectTeam update question to reflect your chagnes

Comment: I have made the reflective changes.