# Join two tables and show the retrieved information in thymeleaf

Tags: java, mysql, spring, join, spring-data-jpa

I work with Spring MVC and JPA. I want to join the data out of two classes (tables) and show data out of both tables via thymeleaf html.

These are the two classes I want to join:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "package_aud")
public class PackageAudited {

@Column(name="id")
private Integer id;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="rev")
private Integer rev;

@Column(name="revtype")
private Integer revtype;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "rev", nullable=true)
private RevisionInfo info;

... more attributes and getters/setters
```

And

```
@Entity
@RevisionEntity(RevListener.class)
@Table(name = "revinfo")
public class RevisionInfo {

@Id
@RevisionNumber
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="rev")
private Integer rev;

@RevisionTimestamp
@Column(name="revtstmp")
private Date revtstmp;

@Column(name="revuser")
private String revuser;

... getters/setters
```

This is the repository where I try to join the tables with a query:

```
public interface PackageAuditedRepository extends 
CrudRepository<PackageAudited, Long> {

@Query("SELECT p, c FROM PackageAudited p join p.info c WHERE p.id =:id AND p.rev = c.rev")
List<PackageAudited> findById(@Param("id") Integer id);
```

Controller entry for the html template:

```
@PostMapping("/listSelectedPackage")
public String selectedPackage(@RequestParam("packageId") Integer packageId, Model model) {
        Iterable<PackageAudited> specificPackageHistory = this.packageAuditedRepository.findById(packageId);
        model.addAttribute("specificPackageHistory", specificPackageHistory);
        return "/package/listSelectedPackage";
}
```

Html template to show the joined data:

```
<table class ="center">
<thead>
    <tr>
        ...
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr th:each="package : ${specificPackageHistory}">
        <td th:text="${package.rev}"> </td>
        <td th:text="${package.id}"> </td>
        <td th:text="${package.revuser}"></td>
        <td th:text="${package.revtstmp}"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My code works when I try to show only the data from the PackageAudited class. My query doesn't get me any results and I'm also not sure if ${package.revuser} and ${package.revtstmp} works.

Comment: i think this question help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43922501/spring-jpa-hibernate-how-to-perform-join-of-two-entities-in-one-repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by adding a getter for RevisionEntity info to PackageAudited and changing the thymeleaf html to:

```
th:text="${package.info.?getRevuser()}"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Put only the PackageAudited as the query result:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM PackageAudited p join fetch p.info c WHERE p.id =:id")
List<PackageAudited> findById(@Param("id") Integer id);
```

Then change the way you refer on the page:

```
<tr th:each="package : ${specificPackageHistory}">
    <td th:text="${package.info.rev}"> </td>
    <td th:text="${package.id}"> </td>
    <td th:text="${package.info.revuser}"></td>
    <td th:text="${package.info.revtstmp}"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've updated my code. Now I still get an error by thymeleaf:

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "package.info.rev" (/package/listSelectedPackage:77)

Comment: I still get the same error: There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "package.info.rev"

I get the error also with *.revuser and *.revtstmp

Comment: is the info object present in each of the PackageAudited entities?

Comment: Yes. The PackageAudited object is a copy of a Package object and saves the data of a specific revision. The timestamp and the user who was logged in during the revision is saved in RevInfo. So every PackageAudited object links to only one RevInfo object. There are Revisions of other things (like User objects) but they all have different rev id numbers, so this shouldn‘t be a problem.